# Marginal standardization with robust error estimation for estimation of risk ratios

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, relative-risk, robust-standard-error, misspecification

I've been using software to calculate multivariate risk ratios from logistic regression models. The basic premise is to predict the risk in everybody with some exposure and then again with the exposure, average the two and take their ratio. The multivariate delta-method is ugly but works.

I know multivariate risk ratios can be estimated from GLMs for binomial outcomes having a log link instead of a logit link. You can also obtain robust error estimates by using a sandwich based estimator which is asymptotically correct regardless of variance structure or mean model specification.

If however, I use the delta-method approach with sandwich errors, an issue is that sandwich based errors do *not* provide robust intervals for the predictions (for heteroscedasticity and model misspecification). So the prediction intervals from marginal standardization are subject to scrutiny. But when we "average them together" I wonder if we land on an estimate that is reflective of the Relative Risk GLM with robust errors. A few case studies have produced very comparable estimates and differences between approaches (using sandwich vs. model based error). Bootstrap and jackknife errors have also provided similar RR error estimates, but they take a long time and create more difficulty in creating reproducible estimates.

Is this approach wrong?